# W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/PlantImages/20230325_151658.jpg

Tags: android, opencv

D/sticky note: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/PlantImages/20230325_151658.jpgFile exists!
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/PlantImages/20230325_151658.jpg

```
Uri uri = AddActivity.uri1;
String path = getFile(uri);

 File file = new File(path);
 file.setWritable(true);
//MeViewHolder
 //MeViewHolder
 if (!file.exists()) { System.out.println("file does not exist"); return; }
// open writable channel
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
   // data input
   byte[] data = "Hello, World!".getBytes();
     outputStream.write(data);
   System.out.println("write success"); }
     catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`
```

file exists, and the path is correct, has permissions, (this file is a picture file)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqHp0.png)

Can process the picture by OpenCV`Image upload code`Bitmap img = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imgCamera.setImageBitmap(img);

```
                // Save the image to the device's MediaStore
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDER_NAME);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }
                String fileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + FOLDER_NAME);
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                try {
                    OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        // Compress and save the image to the OutputStream
                        img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);
                        outputStream.close();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        AddActivity.uri1 = uri;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`
```

Comment: `if (!file.canRead()) { return;}`

Comment: Which Android version of used device?

Comment: Which app created that file?

Comment: The Android version of used device is 12 ; The file is crated MediaStore.Images by Camera.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand. If you use the MediaStore to get an uri for a file you will get an uri. A content scheme. Not a file path like /storage/...

Comment: Please share errors and stack traces as text rather than screenshots. This will help to understand why: [ask]